# Multiparticle simulation and Velocity Verlet Algorithm

Tags: simulations, molecular-dynamics

The Velocity Verlet algorithm requires using an updated particle acceleration to compute and updated velocity. If that acceleration depends on a force that depends on distance to the other particles, am I correct in assuming that the algorithm needs to broken up into following:

For *all* particles:

1. Compute v(t+dt/2) = v(t) + dt*a(t)/2
2. Compute x(t+dt) = x(t) + dt*v(t+dt/2)

For particle i:

3. Compute a(t+dt) for i using ALL particle's x(t+dt)
4. Compute v(t+dt) for i using v(t+dt) = v(t) + (a(t)+a(t+dt))/2*dt

In other words, I have to update ALL of the particle positions before getting the updated acceleration for a given particle to move it?

Comment: It is arguable that this belongs on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ rather than here. Nonetheless, I've offered an answer. Also I'm editing your question to improve layout, you may like to double check for errors.

Comment: Have you bothered to look up anything about numerical algorithms of particle simulations? This should be covered in the very same discussion you find even the phrase "velocity Verlet" (probably before, though).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, you need to update *all* the particle positions before evaluating the new accelerations.

Steps 3 and 4 apply to all particles $i$. In fact, it usually makes sense to compute all the accelerations together, from the forces, because (say, in the case of pairwise interactions) the force on $i$ due to $j$ is just the negative of that on $j$ due to $i$.

Comment: Note that your second paragraph is only useful for small number of particles. When $n$ is large, the $\mathcal O\left(n^2\right)$ algorithm you imply it's way too slow & you need smarter algos.

Comment: @KyleKanos I am not implying an $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ all pairs algorithm. I simply said that it makes sense to compute all the forces together. With a proper list structure (or even on a parallel machine), there are efficient implementations that take advantage of computing the force between each pair just once.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you are using is the half step algorithm. You may use simply,
`STEP1:x(t+dt)=x(t)+v(t)*dt+0.5*a(t)*dt*dt
 STEP2:calculate forces F(t+dt). 
 STEP3:v(t+dt)=v(t)+0.5*(a(t)+F(t+dt)/m)*dt.
 STEP4:a(t+dt)=F(t+dt)/m.`

and you have to calculate the above for all particle's.

**Trick** for speed for heavy simulation: 
1. better take nearest neighbor interaction only, depending upon the strength of the force.
2. for paired forces, count the interaction only once.